# Change toasts presented by Lollipop's Screen Pinning

Tags: android, android-screen-pinning

I've been looking for a way to change the default messages that Lollipop's Screen Pinning shows when the user attempts to leave the pinned screen, but I didn't find the answer anywhere... the closest thing I found was [this question...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32780113/how-to-disable-toast-messages-generated-in-screen-pinning) so I thought it would be a good question to post in here just in case somebody else have done this customization before or knows for sure if this is impossible to achieve.

Thanks in advance!